# LibGDX / OpenGL Stencil Buffer masking not working

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, stencil-buffer

I'm using LibGDX to render 2d fog-of-war type functionality. This involves drawing a dark rectangle over the entire map with transparent holes in it where you can see the map below. I'm attempting to use OpenGl stencil buffer to create the circular masks, but I can't seem to get the logic correct.

The code below correctly draws the dark rectangle (the fog) but the circular masks are not being stenciled. i.e. the entire map is dark.

```
 batch.end();

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);
    //always write the clipped holes to the stencil
    Gdx.gl.glStencilFunc(GL20.GL_ALWAYS, 0x1, 0xffffffff);
    Gdx.gl.glStencilMask(0xFF);
    Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(gameUi.camera.combined);
   
     //test circle
    shapeRenderer.circle(0, 0, 1000, 100);

    shapeRenderer.end();


    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    //only draw the fog of war where stencil is 0
    Gdx.gl.glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0x0, 0xffffffff);
    Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);


    //draw fog of war
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(gameUi.camera.combined);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(radarFog);
    int dimension = gameUi.mapConfig.getDimension();
    shapeRenderer.rect(-dimension,-dimension,dimension*3,dimension*3);
    shapeRenderer.end();

    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);

    batch.begin();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get this to work with stencils. There were some issues with the stencil ops I was using but the code below is working for me.

```
        //enable stencil and depth testing
        gl.glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        //enable blending because our fog has alpha
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        //stencil op which writes to stencil when test passes
        gl.glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
        //clear stencil buffer
        gl.glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
        //always pass the stencil test and mask to accept all values
        gl.glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
        gl.glStencilMask(0xFF);

        //draw our cut out circles
        drawCircles();

        //change stencil function to only match where stencil was written
        gl.glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
        //change mask so nothing is written to stencil
        gl.glStencilMask(0x00);


        drawFog();

        //disable features
        gl.glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
        gl.glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve a *fog-of-war* effect is by keeping a `Framebuffer` that you write transparent pixels to, and then draw that buffer ontop of your game view:

[image]

The steps are more or less:

1. Draw game
2. Update fog-of-war buffer
3. Draw fog-of-war ontop of the game

   ```
   // Draw the game
   batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
   batch.begin();
       batch.draw(map, 0, 0);
   batch.end();

   // Draw the fog of war to a previously initialized FrameBuffer without first clearing the buffer
   fogOfWarBuffer.begin(); 
       shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
       shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
           shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
           shapeRenderer.circle(position.x, position.y, 64, 16);
       shapeRenderer.end();
   fogOfWarBuffer.end();

   // Draw the FrameBuffer as a texture
   batch.begin();
       batch.draw(fogOfWarRegion, 0, 0, camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight);
   batch.end();
   ```

I know this is technically not answering your question about stencil buffers, but it's an easy way to achieve *fog-of-war*.

Full source code for the animation above;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class FogOfWarGame extends Game {
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture map;
    FrameBuffer fogOfWarBuffer;
    TextureRegion fogOfWarRegion;
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 direction = new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f);

    @Override
    public void create() {
        position = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2.0f);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2.0f, camera.viewportHeight / 2.0f, 0.0f);
        camera.update();

        map = new Texture("zelda.png");

        fogOfWarBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        fogOfWarBuffer.begin();
        {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }
        fogOfWarBuffer.end();

        fogOfWarRegion = new TextureRegion(fogOfWarBuffer.getColorBufferTexture());
        fogOfWarRegion.flip(false, true);

        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        position.add(direction);
        if (MathUtils.random() > 0.9f)
            direction.rotateDeg(MathUtils.random(-45, 45));

        // Draw the game
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
            batch.draw(map, 0, 0);
        batch.end();

        // Draw the fog of war to a previously initialized FrameBuffer without first clearing the buffer
        fogOfWarBuffer.begin();
            shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
            shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
                shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
                shapeRenderer.circle(position.x, position.y, 64, 16);
            shapeRenderer.end();
        fogOfWarBuffer.end();

        // Draw the FrameBuffer as a texture
        batch.begin();
            batch.draw(fogOfWarRegion, 0, 0, camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I'm using the scene2d API and even when setting the projection matrix the circle is not rendered in the correct spot. Might have something to do with my framebuffer needing to be much larger than the screen, whereas your example just matches the screen. It also appears to be much slower than the stencil.

Comment: That is a good point, @TheShoeShiner, this method does not work well when the map is much bigger than the window.